# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL

Tags: javascript, localhost, jsfiddle

I'm trying to use this code for a navigation bar but

a. its not working 
b. i receive this warning in Google chrome (Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL)

It all works perfect on Jsfiddle and the website i'm in the middle of making is very basic with no other javascript on the page so i don't see the problem.

I've tried loading the code from the head, the body and also referenced it as an external js file but no luck with either one.

Here is the link to the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/zegermens/9hYey/

If anyone can help me with this code or explain why it wont be working on localhost it would be amazing.

Comment: Post your website's code, since the jsfiddle works. You've got a syntax error in it somewhere.

Comment: On which line does Chrome see an unexpected token? And please post your code along with the question, not somewhere off-site (although an additional demo is never bad).

Comment: Copying from jsFiddle tends to introduce invisible "illegal" characters, especially at the end of the code.

Answer (score 2):

I have had this problem/error in the past and it was due to not having and ending `;` semicolon.

It especially happens when I am loading multiple jQuery libraries or javascript objects in one file.

For example:

```
(function ($) {
   // Class 1
})(window.jQuery); // <- this is missing

(function ($) {
   // Class 2
})(window.jQuery)
```

Without that semicolon the classes attempt to call each other. like so `...})(window.jQuery)(function...`

Check your file for needed semicolons that could be missing.

Comment: The classes don't merge together, they try to call each other, since `()` technically is a function call. Some/most libraries are smart and put a `;` at the top of their code, to make sure it terminates any open code before it. I guess it's also good to put one after their code as well.

Comment: Sorry I meant merge as in they come together side by side. I will fix that. Thanks

Comment: I ran into a similar problem a few days ago when I wrote something like `(foo && bar) (baz && quux)` when I meant `(foo && bar) || (baz && quux)`. I couldn't figure out why it wasn't a syntax error, and it's because it's valid function call syntax. This is one of the misfeatures of using a dynamically typed language.